# Python pandas finding rows that match first 6 characters

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

I have a function that matches rows with pdf files in a directory, and appends them to a merger to make one file, per column in an excel. So if 3 columns populated then I get 3 PDF packs.

How can I only match the excel row data with the first 6 digits of the file name?
In the excel, rows will be `123456` but the PDF file name might be `123456-J`?

```
        ...
        for header in models:
            merger = PdfFileMerger()
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                if type(row[header]) == str:
                    merger.append('folder/directory' + row[header]) # How can I match only the first 6 digits?
            merger.write(f"#{order_num} ({header}) test.pdf")
            merger.close()
```

Comment: What is merger ?

Comment: `from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger`

Comment: it helps if you put the layout of your excel and how pdf are stored.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a list of all available files, which you could retrieve with `glob`. Then find a match that starts with the contents of `row[header]`, and pass that url to PdfFileMerger:

```
from glob import glob

files = glob('folder/directory/*.pdf')
...
    for header in models:
        merger = PdfFileMerger()
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if type(row[header]) == str:
                file_match = [i for i in files if i.split('/')[-1].startswith(row[header])]
                if file_match:
                    merger.append(file_match[0]) # How can I match only the first 6 digits?
        merger.write(f"#{order_num} ({header}) test.pdf")
        merger.close()
```

A faster approach would be to replace the filenames in the df:

```
files = glob('folder/directory/*.pdf')

for i in files:
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: i if type(x) == str and x in i else x)

order_num = '123456'

def merge(col):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in df:
        merger.append(pdf)
    merger.write(f"#{order_num} ({col.name}) test.pdf")
    merger.close()

df.apply(merge)
```

Comment: Thanks @RJ Adriaansen, the potential quantity I'd be looking at for that approach is well over 10,000. Is there a way to just match the first 6 characters in a filename? Or ignore an appended "-X" where X can be any letter?

Comment: yes, you could replace the values in the df directly with the matching paths, that would save iterations, see updated answer